# Does a well-fitting model have shallower chi-square minima than a poorly fitting one?

Tags: chi-squared-test, modeling

I am trying to fit some data with a range of models with some variable parameters, to determine which of the possible models best describes the data. I have noticed that if the model is a poor fit, the variable parameters are often well constrained and if it is a better fit they often have much larger uncertainties.

It seems that poor models frequently have steep chi-square minima (with the minimum still unacceptably high), and good models have shallow ones with values acceptable over a large range of the parameters. Is this a general rule and, if so, are there any good references for understanding it?